Not able to launch desktop electron js app using playwright
I'm attempting to use playwright to automate an electron js application but unfortunately the  executable path that I am providing is not targeting the app and when I am providing the path to different electron js app(slack) it is launching the app. Little help would be highly appreciated.
this is the code for it -
import { test, expect, type Page } from '@playwright/test';
import { _electron as electron, ElectronApplication } from 'playwright';

test('get started', async ({ page }) => {
    // test.setTimeout(150000);
    let electronApp: ElectronApplication = 
    await electron.launch({    
            executablePath: 'path to my electron js app '      
    });


Please provide more details. Is the app running when you perform your tests or do you start the app before you conduct your tests? In playwright.config.ts you can set up your test server by adding webServer before executing your tests. Where´ve you set up the baseURL or .goto() ? please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Sorry i am all new to this desktop automation so basically what i am trying to do here is  simply launch a desktop app through the above script
executablePath: 'C:\Program Files\neuphony-desktop-app\Neuphony.exe'
webserver is not yet setup do i need to ?

Yes, you can setup a server/app configuration via webserver which will be started before tests are performed.
